# Same first fundamental form and isometry

Tags: differential-geometry

The following is from *Elementary Differential Geometry* by A.N. Pressley, page 102.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Why is the author using the different choices of curves to prove $E_1=E_2$, $F_1=F_2$ and $G_1=G_2$, when it can be obtained by comparing the coefficients Eq(3)?

Answer (score 2):

$A + 2B + C = D + 2E + F$ does not imply that $A = D$, $B =E$, and $C = F$!

Example:

$$1 + 2\cdot 2 + 1 = 6 = 2 + 2 \cdot 1 + 2$$

Comment: Okay, my another question is that what is the meaning of doing this choice of curves? I feel like this is purposely done just to get the proof done. Why must this hold true? Why does the author make one parameter constant just to prove $E_1=E_2$? What if it cannot be done?

Comment: I am not sure what the snippet of text you've shown is trying to accomplish (what is the overarching theorem/goal). And I am not sure how pedagogically the author arranged his/her definitions. So it is a bit difficult to address why that choice of curves work. // But with almost all constructive proofs in mathematics, you have to make a choice to "get the job done". In this case the author held one of the two values constant "because he could". In fact, from elementary linear algebra, **any** three generic curves passing through $u_0, v_0$ will do the job. The specific choice of holding ...

Comment: ... $u_0$ and $v_0$ fixed merely simplifies the algebra.

Comment: Yes but that ‘making the choice to get the job done’ part is causing me trouble. Makes me very uncomfortable. Is it not something like affirming the consequent? Making choice that would get the proof done? How can we be sure it is justified?

Comment: Like I said: you need to show what the theorem statement is for me to know what you are objecting to then.

Comment: The statement is this A diffeomorphism $f$ :$S_1 \arrow S_2$ is an isometry iff for any surface patch $\sigma_1$ of $S_1$ the patches $\sigma_1$ of $S_1$ and $f \circ \sigma_1 = \sigma_2$ of $S_2$ have the same fundamental form. 
I’ve included a new picture in the question too.

Comment: Okay, now it is more clear. In the part of the proof you are asking about, the goal is to show that the **hypothesis** of "$f$ is an isometry" implies the **conclusion** of the first fundamental forms are equal. And this is why you can choose curves! By hypothesizing that $f$ is an isometry you can make use of ANY curves to make your argument. The author has found that to argue that the three values that appear in the first fundamental form are equal, you just need to use THREE well-chosen curves.

Comment: In other words: the hypothesis gave you more information then you need, and you can feel free to just use some of them and not all.

Comment: Yes but my only confusion is how he applies the conclusion of curves (i) and (ii) for the curve (iii). For example curve (i) gives $E_1$ = $E_2$, how can this be true for curve (ii) and (iii)? If any of the curves give all the three equalities I don’t think I have a problem. But this mixing things together. For the first curve $Es$ are equal and for the second curve $Gs$ are equal. How can this be true for thr third curve?

Comment: @danny: the quantities $E_1, E_2$ are defined **independently of the choice of curves**. They are defined once the coordinate systems $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first curve, with $v=v_0$ has $\dot v =0$,
the second, with $u=u_0$ has $\dot u=0$ so are used to compare only the coefficients $E_i$ and $G_i$ . Than we need another curve to compare the other coefficients.

Comment: Yes that’s true, but why in the first place such a curve as the first curve should exist? Even if so then we get $E_1=E_2$ similarly for $G$, then these results are used to prove $F_1=F_2$ but for that $E_1$ may not be equal to $E_2$ right? How can we use a value obtained from the first curve to find another value from the third curve?

Comment: The two forms are equals iff they are the same for **all** the curves.

Comment: But that’s what we have to prove right? Don’t know why, but this has been bothering me for two days. Unable to convince myself.